# Localhost being prepended to Fetch request

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm using a https url and for whatever reason fetch is adding localhost:300 to the start of the url. When I check the url that it's calling I get this: http://localhost:3000/%E2%80%8Bhttps://www... anybody know why?

```
  // load API 
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://www.URL.com/api/route').then(res => {
      return res.json()
    }).then(data => {
      this.setState({
        orders : data
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing the code you're using. Please add the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: please add your piece of code...

Comment: Add your code for fetch request.

Comment: You must have some processing of your request, try to create index.html file with same fetch in <script> tag and see if you get same problem. Maybe dev server configured to add that localhost to any request?

Comment: Are you using WSL? I just started noticing this after updating Windows and I didn't previosuly have an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem, and it was because I had a whitespace character in the beginning of the url before "https...". Perhaps you had a similar problem so fetch read the url as a relative path instead.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem in react application I was building. Mistyped URL was my mistake.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32789447)