# Next.JS - localhost is prepended when making external API call

Tags: next.js, fetch, wsl-2

I got a simple Next app where I'm making an external API call to fetch some data. This worked perfectly fine until a couple days ago - when the app is making an API request, I can see in the network tab that the URL that it's trying to call, got Next app's address (`localhost:3000`) prepended in front of the actual URL that needs to be called e.g.: instead of `http://{serverAddress}/api/articles` it is calling `http://localhost:3000/{serverAddress}/api/articles` and this request resolves into `404 Not Found`.

To make the API call, I'm using `fetch`. Before making the request, I've logged the URL that was passed into `fetch` and it was correct URL that I need. I also confirmed my API is working as expected by making the request to the expected URL using *Postman*.

I haven't tried using other library like `axios` to make this request because simply it doesn't make sense considering my app was working perfectly fine only using `fetch` so I want to understand why is this happening for my future experience.

I haven't made any code changes since my app was working, however, I was *Dockerizing* my services so I installed *Docker* and *WSL2* with *Ubuntu*. I was deploying those containers on another machine, now both, the API I'm calling and Next app are running on my development machine directly when this issue is happening.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092529/localhost-being-prepended-to-fetch-request) post, I confirmed I don't have any whitespaces in the URL, however, as one comment mentions, I installed *WSL2*, however, I am not running the app via WSL terminal. Also, I've tried executing `wsl --shutdown` to see if that helps, unfortunately the issue still persists. If this is the cause of the issue, how can I fix it? Uninstall *WSL2*? If not, what might be another possible cause for the issue?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The code I'm using to call `fetch`:

`fetcher.js`

```
export const fetcher = (path, options) =>
    fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}${path}`, options)
        .then(res => res.json());
```

`useArticles.js`

```
import { useSWRInfinite } from 'swr';
import { fetcher } from '../../utils/fetcher';

const getKey = (pageIndex, previousPageData, pageSize) => {
  if (previousPageData && !previousPageData.length) return null;
  return `/api/articles?page=${pageIndex}&limit=${pageSize}`;
};

export default function useArticles(pageSize) {
  const { data, error, isValidating, size, setSize } = useSWRInfinite(
    (pageIndex, previousPageData) =>
      getKey(pageIndex, previousPageData, pageSize),
    fetcher
  );

return {
    data,
    error,
    isValidating,
    size,
    setSize
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code sample with your fetch API call?

Comment: Sure, updated the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be missing protocol (http/https) in your API call. Fetch by default calls the host server URL unless you provide the protocol name.

Either put it into env variable:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://server_address
```

Or prefix your fetch call with the protocol name:

```js
fetch(`http://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}${path}`, options)
```